# Flutter optional Assets

Tags: flutter, dart, build

I'm building an app in Flutter, and I'm using the `flutter-dotenv` package so we can change things around on development time or testing time without changing the code.

I can see that for it to work I must include a `.env` asset in the pubspec YAML file, however, that .env file may or may not be there. Currently I'm just using an empty .env file, but I don't think this is ideal.

Is there any way to instruct the flutter build process to copy a file only if it exists?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hope this tutorial will help you: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-api-keys-dart-define-env-files/